# How to fix my date formula

Tags: crystal-reports

My data comes out as CYYMMDD and I am using the current formula below. When the date of the field is actually 0/00/00, it comes through to Crystal as 0.00 and then when my formula below converts it, it shows up as 11/30/99. How do I have it show as N/A?

```
Local StringVar x := ToText({FIELD}, "0");
Local NumberVar c := (ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1)) + 1) * 10;
x := RIGHT(x, 6);
Local NumberVar y := ToNumber(ToText(c, "0") & LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 4);
Local NumberVar m := ToNumber(LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 2);
Local NumberVar d :=ToNumber(x);

Dateserial(y,m,d)
```

Comment: show some examples of the data that comes from your database. Including what the 0.00 looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if database.field=0.0
then "N/A"
else
Local StringVar x := ToText({FIELD}, "0");
Local NumberVar c := (ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1)) + 1) * 10;
x := RIGHT(x, 6);
Local NumberVar y := ToNumber(ToText(c, "0") & LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 4);
Local NumberVar m := ToNumber(LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 2);
Local NumberVar d :=ToNumber(x);

ToText(Dateserial(y,m,d))
```

Edit-------------------------------------------------------

```
Local StringVar x := ToText({FIELD}, "0");
Local NumberVar c := (ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1)) + 1) * 10;
Local NumberVar y;
Local NumberVar m ;
Local NumberVar d;

IF {FIELD}=0.0
THEN "N/A"
ELSE
(
y:= ToNumber(ToText(c, "0") & LEFT(RIGHT(x, 6), 2));
m:= ToNumber(LEFT(RIGHT(x, 4), 2));
d:=ToNumber(RIGHT(x, 2));

ToText(Dateserial(y,m,d))
)
```

Comment: Hi Siva, I get this error msg: "The string is non-numeric", then it highlights the following in the formula: ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1))

Comment: you are getting some non integer values... those can be characters hence conversion is failing... I would suggest you to see just `ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1))` to check what exactly it is extracting

Comment: I dont get that error unless I add this part:
     if database.field=0.0
     then "N/A"
     else

Comment: Any idea Siva? Appreciate the help.

Comment: There are lot of unnecessary things written in your code.. formatted and posting the answer... IT should work now.. If not working provide more information like how data is stored in {Field} and what is the final output you are looking for.... check edit

Comment: Accepted! :) Thanks